# Angular sort result of function

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I must order results by the result of my function.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in dataTeam | orderBy : '{{getResults(x.id)}}'">
     <p>{{getResults(x.id) | number: 2}} % - {{x.team_name}}</p>
</div>
```

getResults is some function that calculate some results, I would like to sort that.

Thanks for help

//****

EDITED

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/team")
.then(function successCallback(response){ 
$scope.dataTeam = response.data.team; }; 

// this is dataTeam 
{ "team": [ 
    { "id": 1, "team_name": "ABC" }, 
    { "id": 2, "team_name": "FGH" }, 
    { "id": 3, "team_name": "MNO" } ] } 

 $scope.getResults = function (item){ 
     /* some function here */ 
     return results; 
 }; 

 //from this JSON a calculate getResults by 

 team_id { 
 "teamStatistic": [ 
 { "team_id": 1, "width": "213", "height": "423" },
 { "team_id": 2, "width": "643", "height": "432" },
 { "team_id": 3, "width": "526", "height": "246" } 
] }
```

Comment: What is the result of `getResults()` function?

Comment: result is some number between 1 and 100

Comment: please post structure of dataTeam

Comment: If you try to use **orderBy** like this, you are going to sort the data in `dataTeam` on the property that follows the `:` which has the value returned by `getResults(x.id)`. Is it what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in dataTeam | orderBy:results">
    <p>{{getResults(x.id) | number: 2}} % - {{x.team_name}}</p>
```

where `results` is a method that receives `x`

```
$scope.results = function(x){
   return x.id;  // or other math 
}

$scope.getResults = function(id){
   return id;  // or other math 
}
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/nomzL122/)</kbd>

Full code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.dataTeam = [{
    "id": 1,
    "team_name": "ABC"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "team_name": "FGH"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "team_name": "MNO"
  }];


  var team_id = {
    "teamStatistic": [{
      "team_id": 1,
      "width": "213",
      "height": "423"
    }, {
      "team_id": 2,
      "width": "643",
      "height": "432"
    }, {
      "team_id": 3,
      "width": "526",
      "height": "246"
    }]
  };

  $scope.results = function(x) {

    var height = 0;

    angular.forEach(team_id.teamStatistic, function(item) {
      if (item.team_id === x.id) {
        height = item.height;
      }
    });
    return height;
  }

  $scope.getResults = function(id) {
    return id;
  }
}
```

*Output:*

```
3.00 % - MNO
1.00 % - ABC
2.00 % - FGH
```

Comment: @mrkibzk updated answer: sorting by height (as example)

Comment: but I want to sort output like this

3.00 % - MNO
2.00 % - FGH
1.00 % - ABC

Comment: sort by what? id, width, height? I think I gave you direction, you can edit my demo to your needs